# Adding html file, css file , few javascript files and a few images to django code?

Tags: html, css, django, static

Suppose I've got a html file, css file , few javascript files and a few images (in short , a website template). How do I include them in my django code ?

Comment: [writing your first views from django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's all you've got, you don't want Django, you just want to serve a static site.

If you want to generate pages dynamically, then the short answer is:

- Put your CSS/JavaScript and images in `STATIC_ROOT` (read the notes on [serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/));
- Put your template in a directory pointed to by [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs);
- Create a [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) that serves your template.

If that doesn't make sense - I'd have a go at the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).